# Кодировка текста выводимого через JS

Tags: php, javascript, кодировка

У меня есть `php` файлы, в каждом файле есть переменная `$name` в ней прописано название страницы, русскими символами. Таких файлов примерно тысяча. В каждом из них разное значение переменной $name.

Есть .js файл, в котором есть следующая функция:

```js
function usersloc(name){_usersonline.document.getElementById('locname').innerHTML=name;}
```

Как я понял, с помощью этой функции определяется: какой из тысячи `php` файлов сейчас выводится, из него берется значение переменной `$name` и выводится на странице.

Все бы хорошо, но, выводится название в непонятных иероглифах. Кодировку везде указал `utf-8`, так как у меня всё в этой кодировке. 
Помогите, пожалуйста, мне решить эту проблему.

Comment: а сам JS сохранён в UTF8 ????

Comment: и php файлы тоже в UTF8 ????

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Comment: да, все в utf-8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JS использует ту кодировку, которую задал браузер при открытии страницы. Чаще всего кодировка определяется следующими тегами:

- Для HTML5:

  ```
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  ```
- Для HTML4:

  ```
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
  ```
- Для XML:

  ```xml
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  ```

Если этих тегов не задано. То смотрится заголовок `Content-Type` HTTP-пакета, который в Вашем случае должен выглядеть как: `Content-Type:text/html; charset=UTF-8`

Если даже сервер не задал кодировку, то браузер выберет кодировку, установленную в нем по-умолчанию.

Comment: это все указано.

Comment: Для обеих страниц, которые подгружаются? Проверяли через developer tools?

Answer (score 0):

Мне помогло подобную проблему решить добавление BOM метки в JS файл.

Comment: Старайтесь писать развернутые ответы, не требующие дополнительных уточнений.